# Base R barplot: legends showing over the bars and bars are out of the x-axis scale

Tags: r, visualization

What goes wrong in this barplot code? The variable names go over the bars and the bars are out of the x-axis scale on the left.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = 5.1,
  x2 = 5.5,
  x3 = 5.2
)

names(df) <- c('word word word word word',
               'word word',
               'word word word word')

df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything())


barplot(height=df_long$value, names=df_long$name, 
        col="#69b3a2",
        horiz=T, las=1,
        xlim = c(1,7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the barbplots want to start at `0` but you set the limits for the x-axis as `xlim = c(1,7)`. This will work:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = 5.1,
  x2 = 5.5,
  x3 = 5.2
)

names(df) <- c('word word word word word',
               'word word',
               'word word word word')

df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything())


barplot(height=df_long$value, names=df_long$name, 
        col="#69b3a2",
        horiz=T, las=1,
        xlim = c(0,7))
```

[image]

EDIT: I found setting the argument `xpd = FALSE` within the `barplot()` funtion cuts off the tail of the barplot. Maybe this helps?

```
barplot(height=df_long$value, names=df_long$name, 
        col="#69b3a2",
        horiz=T, las=1,
        xpd = FALSE,
        xlim = c(1,7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ludwig, your edit was actually very necessary. Your initial answer only partly fixed the issue. The plot was still flawed because number 0 shouldn't have been in the scale because the survey data doesn't have such an option/value.

Comment: Glad it helped.